# Convert markdown to Rd, or define custom markdown conversion rules?

Tags: r, markdown

I'm trying to write documentation for an R package in Markdown, and have it converted to an Rd file.

I guess another way to look at this is that I want a framework that recognises various markdown constructs and allows me to specify how these should be rendered, e.g.:

- `` `text in backticks` `` gets converted to `\code{text in backticks}`
- `**text**` is converted to `\bold{text}`
- markdown lists are converted to `\itemize{...}`

and so on.

Is there something that will let me do this? The `pander` package in R (wrapping around pandoc) looked promising, but I'm not sure that I can specify conversion rules (for example it converts backticks using `\texttt` and I want `\code`), and it also generates a complete standalone document rather than just my input snippet converted.

The `markdown` package for R appears to just do markdown -> HTML.
It looks like it *might* have support for custom renderers but I'm not sure how to write one (it looks like I have to write C code?)

I'm after something like this:

```
convertMarkdown(myTextSnippet,
                backticks = function (txt) {
                    return(paste0('\\code{', txt, '}'))
                },
                bold = function(txt) {
                    return(paste0('\\bold{', txt, '}'))
                },
                unordered.list = function (items) {
                    itms <- paste('\\item', items, collapse='\n')
                    return(paste('\\itemize{', itms, '}', sep='\n'))
                },
                # ... and so on
)
```

Does such a thing exist?

(Bonus: I just want to be able to embed markdown in my `roxygen` comments, so was thinking of converting parts of the comments from markdown to rd, and then running roxygen on the output).

Comment: Why not convert the whole thing and then read in and gsub the way you'd like.  Pandoc does pretty much everything you want but `gsub` out `\\texttt{` for `\\code{` etc.  Have a look at [this](https://github.com/trinker/reports/blob/master/R/QC.R) and steal like it's your job.

Comment: "Why not convert the whole thing" - what do you mean? You mean just use pandoc to do markdown -> latex and then rely on gsub to convert latex -> Rd?

Comment: Yeah exactly. Would that work?  Just curious, why not `roxygen2`?

Comment: Hmm, I suppose it might, though it seems a bit hacky. And oh, I meant `roxygen2`. I'll have to find some way to feed the modified text into `roxygenise`.

Comment: Oh I got you I missed the `roxygen2` use.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to write a custom renderer, probably using some C. I'd recommend emailing Jeff Horner for advice.

Comment: IMHO `pander` can help you with this process, e.g. `pandoc.verbatim.return('foo')` would return "foo" as a string between markdown formatted code tags (backticks) or as indented code block defined by `style`. `\\code` tag is not supported as not a `pandoc` syntax, but I would be happy to add that too on demand in a few days (just like the other styles for e.g. `pandoc.strong`). Please open a ticket at https://github.com/Rapporter/pander if you would build on `pander` after all.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee : I submitted a pull request ( https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/pull/244) that implements this for roxygen2 yesterday -- waiting for a reply from the serious people to tell me how wrong I am ;)

Answer (score 4):

Have you seen the maxygen package by @gabor-csardi?

https://github.com/gaborcsardi/maxygen

It basically lets you write roxygen headers in Markdown.

[UPDATE]
These changes have been incorparated to the roxygen2 package and will go out with the version 6 release. From GitHub:

> Most fields can now be written using Markdown markup instead of the
>   traditional Rd language. You can turn on Markdown globally by adding
>   Roxygen: list(markdown = TRUE) to DESCRIPTION. The @md / @noMd tags
>   turn Markdown parsing on / off for the given block. See the 'markdown'
>   vignette for more details (#364, #431, #499, #506, #507), by
>   @gaborcsardi

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `md2rd` function suggested by Fabian Scheipl: see [roclet-md2rd.R](https://github.com/fabian-s/roxygen/blob/20dcae9e96f9cc3afd1941a574d2bf709d586874/R/roclet-md2rd.R) for details.